# HSQLDB AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER call http GET request

Tags: triggers, classpath, hsqldb

I am working with a software (lobster _data) that has an HSQLDB 2.0.26 in it's calsspath. It is using it for internal stuff.

I am wondering if it is possible to create an AFTER UPDATE trigger that calls an http endpoint after a row has been updated.
I never worked with DB triggers, so this is quite new to me.

I learned, that it is possible to run AFTER UPDATE TRIGGERS.
I also learned, that it is possible to call JAVA classes as functions from HSQLDB.

**my Java class could look like this:**

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HttpGetFunction {

   public static String httpGet(String url) throws Exception {
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    
        Scanner in = new Scanner(con.getInputStream());
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            response.append(in.nextLine());
        }
        in.close();
    
        return response.toString();
    }
}
```

**My function definition in HSQL could look like this**

```
CREATE FUNCTION http_get(url VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS VARCHAR(4096) 
LANGUAGE JAVA DETERMINISTIC NO SQL EXTERNAL NAME 'HttpGetFunction.httpGet';
```

**and a call (not yet a TRIGGER) woul loók like this**

```
SELECT http_get('https://www.example.com') FROM DUAL;
```

But I do not get the class loaded into the classpath?
When I run the above code to create the function, I get a ClassNotFoundException.

How can I check wheather a java class is in the hsql classpath?

Answer (score 0):

If ound out that I have to name the function fully qualified.

```
CREATE FUNCTION http_get(url VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS VARCHAR(4096) 
LANGUAGE JAVA DETERMINISTIC NO SQL EXTERNAL NAME 'my.packe.strcuture.HttpGetFunction.httpGet';
```

insteat of

```
CREATE FUNCTION http_get(url VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS VARCHAR(4096) 
LANGUAGE JAVA DETERMINISTIC NO SQL EXTERNAL NAME 'HttpGetFunction.httpGet';
```